# SQL: Max Value is not selecting the Max

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL Code is the following:

```
Select Model,Max(Price) FROM Printer GROUP BY Model ORDER BY Max(Price) DESC;
```

It should return the following:

```
MODEL   MAX PRICE
3007    899
3003    899
```

However, it instead returns this:

```
MODEL   MAX PRICE
3007    899
3003    899
3002    139
3004    120
3006    100
3005    99
```

What am I doing wrong?  I tried changing or removing Order by and the like, but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: That SQL's doing exactly what you asked it to do, by the looks of it. Can you explain the result you want in plain words?

Comment: "but it did not fix my problem." What problem? It looks fine.

Comment: I am getting a lot more fields than I want.  I only want to see the records that are the highest value out of all the records.  In this case 899 is the highest value and I only want to see those 2 Records for Model 3007 and Model 3003

Comment: `group by` is giving you the max price per model. You have six models so you get six rows (not fields), one for each model. That is what `group by` clauses do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cleaner method to get what I wanted

```
SELECT 
Model, 
Price
FROM
Printer
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM Printer)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the maximum priced rows, then you need to limit the number of rows.  You seem to want `rank()`:

```
SELECT Model, max_price
FROM (SELECT Model, MAX(Price) as max_price,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(PRICE) DESC NULLS LAST) as seqnum
      FROM Printer p
      GROUP BY Model
     ) p
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your try.  For some reason I get blank results in my query.

Comment: @BillBisco . . . If you have `NULL` values for `PRICE`, then that could happen.  I added `NULLS LAST` to handle that situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 12.1 or later:

```
select model, max(price) from printer
group by model
order by max(price) desc
fetch first row with ties;
```